# My laptop powers off (not orderly shutdown), only if I move it

Tags: laptop

My laptop randomly powers off, only if I move it. Sometimes it powers off, and sometimes it doesn't. I keep my computer on for over twelve hours a day, and it never powers off, as long as I don't move it. When I move it, sometimes it will, and sometimes it won't (about 70% of the time it will power off). I don't hear anything rattling when I shake my PC. The move could be a 4-cm move, and it'll happen, or it could be a full 2 meters, etc.

By power off I mean it just goes black, it suddenly turns off, as if you had a desktop and unplugged the power source.  I don't have any external devices connected to my laptop.

Any guesses on why? I've had this computer for four years without any problem like this before.

Comment: Make sure nothing is connected to it when you move it, and then (assuming that) , there may be an intermittent circuit flaw on the motherboard. I do not think anything else would cause this.

Comment: @John ur assumption is right, nothing is connected. and how would I fix what you have stated? or do I need a professional

Comment: You would need to get it serviced and see if it can be economically fixed.

Comment: **If** you have anything attached to it (say, a USB mouse), try unplugging it and see what happens when you move it. A short in  a cable could also trigger a power off. By the way, it is an actual orderly shutdown or does it simply power off?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani it powers off, sorry I should have clarified that. i updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have a loose ribbon cable, or perhaps a bad soldering point.  Have someone qualified disassemble the laptop and have a look around.

Comment: Pretty much this. Your laptop has a hardware fault that is triggered by the physics involved in picking it up. To fix this you'll need a qualified hardware technician.

Comment: i guess the general consesus is it's probably hardware and something I don't know about. i will get a pro when I can thank you